# Can I add backgroundColor as custom prop to react native elements button?

Tags: react-native

I've made a custom button from the react native elements button with 'title' and 'onPress' as props but I want to be able to change the background color of the button from inside the JSX of a screen and I can't work out how to put it in as a prop because it's inside the 'buttonStyle' prop.  I've tried adding it as a prop as below and various other ways I've tried but I can't get it to work....does anyone know if it's possible and how?  My code is below (I've stripped out a load of other irrelevant props so it is clear what I'm asking):

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { View } from "react-native";

const BandButton = ({ onPress, title }) => {
    return (

  <Button
    title={title}
    onPress={onPress} 
    buttonStyle={{
      height: 60,
      borderRadius: 5,
      backgroundColor:{backgroundColor}

    }}

  />
  )
};

export default BandButton;
```

The button in JSX:

```
<BandButton 
            title='Add details'
            onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Create')}
            buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FF9800'}}

            />
```

Thank you anyone who can help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { View } from "react-native";

const BandButton = ({ onPress, title, customStyles }) => {
    const defaultStyles = {
      height: 60,
      borderRadius: 5,
    }
    return (
      <Button
        title={title}
        onPress={onPress} 
        buttonStyle={[defaultStyles, customStyles]}
      />
  )
};

export default BandButton;
```

Now use that component like so:

```
<BandButton 
    title='Add details'
    onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Create')}
    customStyles={{backgroundColor: '#FF9800'}}
/>
```

Comment: OMG that's brilliant!!!!!  Thank you so much - I've been struggling with that for days!!!  As a matter of interest is there anywhere I could have googled that?  Thank you again :-))

Comment: Glad it helped! And yes there is an article on RN's official website: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is correct and I have used it myself. One question, just out of curiosity, why do you have double brackets {{ }} when passing the prop to the custom component (in customStyles={{backgroundColor: '#FF9800'}}. Would really appreciate the reply. Thanks!

Comment: The first bracket is a JSX syntax and the second one is you basically assigning  an object to a prop. Take for example, ```let obj = {prop: true}; <Comp style={obj}/>```

Answer (score 0):

The react-native supports style like this

```
style={{backgroundColor: option.color}}
```

Try to do the same:

```
backgroundColor:backgroundColor
```

Where `backgroundColor` should be a string like `'#ff0000'`

Comment: Thank you for answering - I tried that previously but it didn't work - the solution above works perfectly though!